# How to make a group of integers randomly "roll around" a 2d grid, decrementing every time, until each equals 0?

Tags: c++, algorithm, multidimensional-array

sorry for the weird question, but I can explain.

Imagine you have 50 marbles that are wet with paint, and you are standing over a large canvas. You will drop each marble in the middle of the canvas, wait until it stops rolling around (assume when the marble stops, it disppears), and then drop your next one until you run out of marbles.

You will notice that when you are finished dropping all the marbles, the canvas is painted all over, with some streaks being darker than others.

That is what I am trying to represent with a 2d grid. So if I were to have 5 marbles, each with a "life" of 2, it would look something like this (given a 10x10 2d array)

```
/*
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
*/
```

Note, we dropped in the middle, then the marble went up and right
We moved twice, so our initial `maxLife == 2` is now `maxLife == 0`, so we move onto the next marble

```
/*
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
*/
```

Note, we dropped in the middle again, then the marble went right
We moved twice, so our initial `maxLife == 2` is now `maxLife == 0`, so we move onto the next marble

```
/*
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 3 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
*/
```

so on, and so on until we have dropped 5 marbles.

This seems basic enough with a simple nested for loop and recursive method to travel across and increment the array until the base case (when `maxLife == 0`), is hit. However, I am not getting expected results.

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int width, height, xMax, xMin, yMax, yMin, numParticles, maxLife, waterLine;

int main()
{

    /* Take in width, height, numParticles, maxLife, removed for code clarity */

    int **land = makeParticleMap(width, height, numParticles, maxLife);
    printIsland(land, width, height);

    return 0;
}

void printIsland(int **land, int width, int height) { ... }

int **makeParticleMap(int width, int height, int numParticles, int maxLife)
{
    int **land;
    land = new int *[height];

    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        land[i] = new int[width]; //we have the 2d array
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            land[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    int x, y = (width + height) / 2;
    while (numParticles != 0) //while we have particles to drop
    {
        particleRoll(land, width, height, x, y, maxLife);
        numParticles--;
    }
    return land;
}

void particleRoll(int **map, int width, int height, int x, int y, int maxLife)
{
    if (maxLife <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    map[x][y]++;
    maxLife--;
    
    int xDir = (randomBool()) ? 1 : -1;
    int yDir = (randomBool()) ? 1 : -1;

    //i + xDir means: i-- or i++, either roll up or down rows, and j--, j++ same thing across columns
    particleRoll(map, width, height, x + xDir, y + yDir, maxLife);
}

bool randomBool() { //returns -1 or 1 }
```

`height` and `width` never change, they are just the sizes of the array, since I am working with an `int**` instead of a `vector`.

I am just getting a `width x height` array of all 0's. I assume that the whole logic problem is within the recursion of `particleRoll`. I tried approaching it in a DFS style search, like the famous Number of Islands algorithm problem. However, I cannot figure out why my code is working like this.

Comment: What is the smallest number of marbles, and shortest marble life, that gives the error? What happens when you remove the random part, so that the direction is always (1,1)?

Comment: Your bounds tests in `particleRoll` have an off-by-one error.  `i > height` should be `i >= height` -- same for `width`.  Your array indexing is backwards too.  The array is allocated as if it is `[width][height]`, but you use `i` as a y-coordinate and `j` as an x-coordinate everywhere else.  Perhaps you should change the allocation in `makeParticleMap` accordingly.  There is no need to save/restore `maxLife` before calling your function.  Learn how pass-by-value works.  I highly recommend using `x` and `y` instead of `i` and `j` because you have errors with those names everywhere.

Comment: if I enter 0 and 0, for numMarbles and marbleLife, the program still does not print out anything, and removing the random part does not do anything either. i am a little confused, because when I call ```makeParticleMap(...)```, since I am instantiating everything to 0, it should still print out a ```m x n``` matrix full of 0's.

Comment: Well, your termination condition won't handle `maxLife` of zero, because you already do a `maxLife--;` before invoking your marble loop.  That will mean `maxLife` is -1 and only decreases.  If the marble doesn't leave the grid bounds then your recursion will keep going until the stack overflows.  Test `maxLife <= 0` instead of `maxLife == 0`.

Comment: Also unclear why you have nested loops inside the `while (numParticles--)` loop.  It looks like this is some kind of early attempt before writing a recursive function to do the rolling.  The issue here is that loop nest performs `numParticles--;` many times before the primary loop is tested again.  At that point, it's highly likely that `numParticles` will be negative, and the loop will not terminate when you expect.

Comment: @paddy thanks for letting me know about my problem with my ```i``` ```j``` and ```height```, ```width``` inconsistencies, they are all fixed. now. i have also done ```maxLife <= 0```, I assume that there is a stack overflow and my compiler isn't telling me.

why would maxLife initially be -1? I am taking in input in the ```int main() ```

Comment: @paddy wow, I didn't even realize. There is no point of using a double for loop, I am traversing the array using the recursive method ```particleRoll```, anyway

Comment: Please read.  I'm saying that if you input maxLife as 0 (which you say you tried), then the line `maxLife--;` _before_ your loop will result in maxLife of -1.  When you pass that into your recursive function, it'll never hit the `maxLife == 0` termination case.

Comment: Note also your marbles always roll diagonally because neither of the two roll directions are ever 0.

Comment: please fix your title

Comment: You seed the pseudo-random number generator every time you call `particleRoll`. You use the current time, which has a granularity of one second, which means that your `xDir` and `yDir` will almost always have the same values. Call `srand(time(NULL))` only once at the beginning of `main`.